# Creating in-memory hashmaps in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I will have my data stored in MongoDb and have multiple collections (equivalent of tables) in the db. Each collection is namespaced and has a whole lot of documents in there. We need to have a fast lookup of our data and hence don't want to query the db each time.

My webapp is spring based. On server startup, i would like to cache all the doucments in the collections into a java Map. Since i'll potentially have close to 40-50 collections, i would like to create those many in-memory maps and not have a single Map which contains all the collections.

What would be the best way to create those many in-memory maps? Or are there any other ways of implementing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One fine day you will crash your server with these maps. For your information mongoDB does cache a lot of stuff. So the dips to mongoDB are not that expensive as you think

> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its
>   cache. System resource monitors show that MongoDB uses a lot of
>   memory, but its usage is dynamic. If another process suddenly needs
>   half the server’s RAM, MongoDB will yield cached memory to the other
>   process.

Comment: The issue is that with each request we might have to query  anywhere between 500-1000 records. And so i'm thinking in totality the reads would be somewhat expensive.

Comment: @user320550 Have you done measurement before reaching the conclusion. Mongo collections are saved using json and if you used an optimised query it may actually be faster than your own code.

Comment: I haven't done any benchmark testing. I'll write something up and will update this comment.

Comment: @user320550 as per my experience with mongo, it should amaze you ;-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan if the java application queries from different servers to the mongodb cluster, although mongodb could cache its documents in it's cluster's memory, the java application still need to query through the network, especially when java applications are in different IDCs from the mongodb, the network communication overhead could be very high when the apps need to query data very often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memcached memory database](http://memcached.org/) to store in memory map.

Comment: So do you mean that the memcached server can be used for storing the mongo collections (json documents)? From the documentation is says its used for storing small chunks of data - `Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering.` Will it scale up to store all my mongo collections?